# Should I emit from a coroutine when collecting from a different flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-sharedflow

I have a use case where I need to trigger on a specific event collected from a flow and restart it when it closes. I also need to emit all of the events to a different flow. My current implementation looks like this:

```kotlin
scope.launch {
    val flowToReturn = MutableSharedFlow<Event>()
    while (true) {
        client
            .connect()                                   // returns Flow<Event>
            .catch { ... }                               // ignore errors
            .onEach { launch { flowToReturn.emit(it) } } // problem here
            .filterIsInstance<Event.Some>()
            .collect { someEvent ->
                doStuff(someEvent)
            }
    }
}.start()
```

The idea is to always reconnect when the client disconnects (`collect` then returns and a new iteration begins) while having the outer flow lifecycle separate from the inner (connection) one. It being a shared flow with potentially multiple subscribers is a secondary concern.

As the `emit` documentation states it is not thread-safe. Should I call it from a new coroutine then? My concern is that the `emit` will suspend if there are no subscribers to the outer flow and I need to run the downstream pipeline regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MutableSharedFlow.emit()` documentation say that it [**is** thread-safe](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/index.html#1664019279%2FFunctions%2F1975948010). Maybe you were accidentally looking at [`FlowCollector.emit()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow-collector/index.html#1193097097%2FFunctions%2F1975948010), which is not thread-safe. MutableSharedFlow is a subtype of FlowCollector but promotes `emit()` to being thread-safe since it's not intended to be used as a Flow builder receiver like a plain FlowCollector. There's no reason to launch a coroutine just to emit to your shared flow.

There's no reason to call `start()` on a coroutine Job that was created with `launch` because `launch` both creates the Job and starts it.

You will need to declare `flowToReturn` before your `launch` call to be able to have it in scope to return from this outer function.

Comment: Yes, indeed I was looking at the wrong `emit`. "There's no reason to launch a coroutine just to emit to your shared flow." what about suspending on emit? I need to collect and `doStuff` regardless of the flow subscribers ability to consume.

Comment: Ok, I suppose that's one reason to launch a coroutine to emit. But then you're trading your buffer size for an unlimited number of coroutine Jobs, which are heavier. Alternatives would be to set the BufferOverflow strategy of the SharedFlow to drop oldest, or to use `tryEmit()`, which would drop an item from being emitted if the buffer is full.

Comment: yeah, good point but it seems like it's not possible to use a size unconstrained buffer.

Comment: @JakubLicznerski why would you want the buffer to be *actually* unconstrained? Wouldn't `MutableSharedFlow<Event>(extraBufferCapacity = Int.MAX_VALUE)` be sufficient (and probably equivalent for all intents and purposes) to ensure `doStuff` is called even with slow collectors on the shared flow?

Comment: the events are rather small data classes carrying a text message or objects. I don't suspect to receive much traffic within this connection

Comment: Also, I guess the buffer shouldn't even be that big because it should technically only be there to handle spikes. If your shared flow collectors are actually constantly slower than the rate of events, you will eventually run out of memory (and you'll run out earlier when using `launch`, as pointed out by @Tenfour04).

Comment: I was thinking of a buffer as a replay buffer in this case. I want all subscribers to receive all events accumulated since the flow start. I know that they will appear eventually so that the buffer won't grow indefinitely (they should be faster than events rate). Wouldn't `Int.MAX_VALUE` replay size be very costly as we would initialize a very big array internally?

Comment: A quick look at the source looks to me like it does. Maybe return `flowToReturn.buffer(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED)` from your function? Downside is redundant buffers for each subscriber.

Comment: yeah, that looks like my case. Thanks!

Comment: *Wouldn't Int.MAX_VALUE replay size be very costly as we would initialize a very big array internally* - good point, sorry for suggesting that.